# MYSQL-PHP handling datetime,timestamp timezone; how to correctly display and save post and update date and time of a post

Tags: php, mysql

I need Advice; I am seriously confused.

On my website people will be posting and updating their comments;so I created two columns, one for save the datetime of post and one the datetime of update.
On insertion and Update I use the function NOW() in triggers(Before insert and before update to set these fields)  to change the dates of these fields but I noticed when display that datetime it will be the same for people living in USA and in PARIS yet it shouldn't be since they are in different TIMEZONE.

Looking for solution to solve the problem;I found that IP2Location API can help get client(from browser) timezone from is IP so that when I want to display I can use that information to convert the dates to client timezone but I read with MYSQL when you are inserting or selecting dates(datetime) they are converted from client timezone to server timezone and from server timezone to clientzone.

From what I understand speaking of client timezone to server; it refers to the php script intepreter;

My questions are :

1. If I set the timezone in php to the timezone I got from the API will the dates in the result of select statement be automatically in that timezone? and Should I use directly the timezone offset or convert it to real timezone to be so accurate: two cities may have same offset but are not in the same timezone.
2. Does the timezone matter when inserting data to database ?
3. If I use convert_TZ function directly in my select statement will mysql still convert that converted datetime or timestamp to the client timezone?
4. What about field of time or date datatype does mysql also convert them to client timezone when display and inserting their values? If Yes how can I oblige mysql to keep them has they are given by the client?

Comment: Best thing to do is save all dates/times as UTC, then convert when needed.

Comment: @swatkins; what do you mean by saving them as UTC; I think they are automatically in it.

Comment: Then all you will need to do is convert to local time based on the user. Have a look here: https://blog.serverdensity.com/handling-timezone-conversion-with-php-datetime/